# How to use NSNumberFormatter to display currency?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsnumberformatter

I want to format a number with [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to be displayed as currency like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[@"0.058" doubleValue]];

[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

This gives me `0,06 €`. But I want it to be `5,8 ct`. Any ideas?

Comment: You could always configure the formatter manually, to precisely your requirements. Do you always want values to be displayed in cents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure NSNumberFormatter like that :

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"ct"];
[numFormatter setMultiplier:100];
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[@"0.058" doubleValue]];
```

Comment: thanks, great so far, is it possible to have just numbers x,x ct without the last 0?

Comment: You can use `setFormat:(NSString *)aFormat` (@"# ##0.0" for you) where format patterns can found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002368-SW1)